# Normalize with gdal_translate

Tags: qgis, gdal

I do not understand the command line when I try to work with gdal_translate in QGIS. I found this at the forum: [Normalize raster values to 0-255](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/normalize-raster-values-to-0-255)

And  tried this:

***"If not, from within QGIS choose Raster -> Conversion - > Translate. Choose your files and options. At the bottom of the window the full gdal_translate command will be displayed. Click edit and add the -scale option."***

When I type the following command into the line I get an error message "wrong parameters"??? Maby the commands are wrong.

[image]

My current grid file has a range from 1 to 9. I need to have a range from 1 to 5 (5 classes).

Comment: have you tried running it without the brackets and commas, i.e. `-scale 1 9 1 5` ? In general, try running it from the command line as it should give you more descriptive error messages.

Comment: Looks like the closing quotation marks are missing, as well as the input layer. This must be a file.

Comment: yes, as Andre Joost mentions you are also missing the input layer. the command should read as follows: `gdal_translate "C:/Tempordner/Your/Input/Image.tif -scale 1 9 1 5 -of GTiff "C:/Tempordener_GIS/QGIS_test/Normalised_Grid.tif"`

Comment: Still one quotation mark too much or missing ;-)

Comment: :-) good point - unaccustomed to using them! `gdal_translate "C:/Tempordner/Your/Input/Image.tif" -scale 1 9 1 5 -of GTiff "C:/Tempordener_GIS/QGIS_test/Normalised_Grid.tif"`

Comment: Tank you all! It works!