# Normalizing satellite image value to 0-255 using QGIS

Tags: qgis, normalize

I have a satellite image and I want to normalize the value between 0-255. I am using QGIS. I used this formula (NewRaster = ( OldRaster - -1 ) * 255 / ( 1 - -1 ) + 0 ) but it does not give me the proper result

Comment: Where did you get that formula?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28559/normalize-raster-values-to-0-255
From this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this normalization, we can use GDAL in QGIS. Follow this procedure

> Processing -> Toolbox -> Processing Toolbox -> Translate (under GDAL)

Choose *Input layer* as your raster file, and open *Additional Parameters*

In *Additional command-line parameters* enter `-scale`

Now enter the output path and file name on *converted* and click **Run**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

QGIS have a SAGA tool called "Raster normalization" or "Raster normalisation" (depends the version) you can use it.

[image]

Be careful if you have a new version of QGIS, there is a fail in the tool description file. It's easy to solve, when you know it, https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424242/200979 .