# Raster normalization

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, normalize

I have change my computer and I install QGIS on the new one. Now I can't normalise a Raster neither the LTR 3.16.16 nor the last one when I could with older 3.16.
I found that the problem is SAGA, or I think that. Just installed QGIS come with SAGA 7.8.2, when I try the Raster normalization I get this view.
[image]

In my old computer, with SAGA 2.3.2 I haven't any problem.
[image]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the SAGA Description file for Raster normalization tool is not properly configured. (Each Description file defines the UI settings of SAGA tool in QGIS processing environment).

**Based on QGIS 3.22.3**

(1) Try and find `grid_calculus_grid_normalization.txt` in QGIS installation folder.

> In my QGIS3.22.3 on Windows10 environment, the Description file is located in `"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.3\apps\qgis\python\plugins\sagaprovider\description"`.

(2) Open the `grid_calculus_grid_normalization.txt` by any text editor application (e.g. Notepad++). You will probably see four lines:

```
Grid Normalization
grid_calculus
QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer|INPUT|Grid|None|False
QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination|OUTPUT|Normalized Grid
```

(3) Then replace it with below:

```
Grid Normalisation
grid_calculus
QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer|INPUT|Grid|None|False
QgsProcessingParameterNumber|RANGE_MIN|Target Range (min)|QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer|0|False|None|None
QgsProcessingParameterNumber|RANGE_MAX|Target Range (max)|QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer|1|False|None|None
QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination|OUTPUT|Normalised Grid
```

(4) You may notice you have just added line4 and line5. Save the file (you may need writing permission to do so).

(5) Restart Raster normalization tool, now you will have `Target Range (min)` and `Target Range (max)` in the UI window (See below).

[image]